# How do I reference each mail item?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I create output showing how many emails were in a defined folder per day.

In the section with XXXXX, how do I reference each mail item so that I can do a regex for a word pattern?

The goal is to find how many emails contained a keyword on a given day.

The desired output is something like this:

```
<date>,<allMessages><messagesWithWord_aaa>,<messagesWithWord_bbb>
2015-01-01,15,2,5
2015-01-01,23,22,0
...
...
```

```vb
Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox").Folders("jobs.keep")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items
    myItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
    ' Determine date of each message:
    For Each myItem In myItems
    
        xxxxxxx
        xxxxxxx
        xxxxxxx
    
        dateStr = GetDate(myItem.SentOn)
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    
'Write output to file
    Dim enviro As String
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    FILEPATH = enviro & "\Desktop\emails.csv"
    Open FILEPATH For Output As 1
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & "," & dict(o) & vbCrLf
        'MsgBox msg
    Next
    Print #1, msg
    Close #1
'Write output to file
    

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetDate(dt As Date) As String
    GetDate = Year(dt) & "-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Day(dt)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the type of item in your code:

```
Dim myMailItem As Outlook.mailItem
....

For each myItem in myItems
    If TypeOf myItem Is MailItem Then
        Set myMailItem = myItem

         XXXXXXXXXXX and rest of code here use myMailItem instead of myItem to get info

    End If
Next myItem
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210275(v=office.11).aspx) methods of the Items class to find the subset of items that match to the specified condition. Iterating through all items in the folder may take a lot of time.

> objnSpace.Folders("Personal Folders").Folders("Inbox")

Use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx) method of the Namespace class to get a folder that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile.

Outlook uses [EntryID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211865(v=office.11).aspx) values for identifying Outlook items uniquely. See [Working with EntryIDs and StoreIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868618.aspx) for more information. If you know the IDs of an item and the folder it's stored in, you can directly reference the item using the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method.